# mouseover animation weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm creating a simple animation with jquery.

The animation consists on a div being slided left when the mouse hovers it.

This is my html:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="content" onmouseover="over(this)" onmouseout="out(this)">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="http://aranciamato.it/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/insetti-700x250.jpg" width="300"/>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            Some useful content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the js:

```
function over(element) {
    $(element).stop().animate({left: "-250"}, 500);
}

function out(element) {
    $(element).stop().animate({left: "0"}, 500);
}
```

This is the css:

```
.item {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 107px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.item .content {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 600px;
    height: 107px;
}

.item .content .image {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.item .content .text{
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 300px;
    width: 250px
}

.item {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

The animation works properly, but I noticed that if you move the cursor over the left border of the `.image` div while the animation is running, it pauses for a moment and then resumes.

I don't know how to explain this better, so [here you can find a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kWbJ7/), and [here you can find a video that demonstrates the behaviour](http://videobam.com/APmeU)

My question is: Why is the animation behaving like this? How can I make the animation continue without pausing?

Comment: Not sure to get your issue but sounds like you should use instead `onmouseenter/mouseleave` events: http://jsfiddle.net/kWbJ7/1/  But better would be to set animation in CSS only

Comment: @A.Wolff I mean it happens something like that: http://videobam.com/APmeU Anyway, both your and Anton's answer do work for me, thanks!

Comment: Thx for the video, now i see what you meant

Comment: @A.Wolff Probably I should have attached it to the question, I'm not english and I don't know how to explain this behaviour in words

Comment: Your english seems better than mine... ;) You explained it well, i was just not sure about it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use mouseenter and mouseleave instead

```
<div class="content" onmouseenter="over(this)" onmouseleave="out(this)">
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/kWbJ7/2/)

Comment: Thanks, that works! I'll accept this answer as soon as SO lets me accept it

Answer (score 1):

Your jsfiddle is working for me. Also, its better for you to use the `$(el).hover()` function jQuery provides, for example:

```
$('.content').hover(function() {
    // Mouseover
}, function() {
    // Mouseout
});
```

Comment: Did you try moving the cursor when the animation is running? You should get something like this: http://videobam.com/APmeU . Anton answer is working for me

Comment: Weird, I am not getting that. its working fine for me. Glad you got it solved!

Comment: @BackSlash `hover` is a shorthand for `onmouseenter/mouseleave`, it would work the same as Anton's answer. But of course then you need to remove inline events declaration from DOM element

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use your hover event on the parent element (in this case .item) and animate the child element (.content). If you're using jQuery, just use .hover () instead of those two mouse events.

Answer (score 0):

When you move the cursor out of the image `div` then a `mouseout` event fires - you move out of the image - and the `out` function is called, making the animation stop. Right after that the `mouseover` event fires - you move over the text - and the `over` function is called.

You attached the event handlers to the `content` div, i.e. they are called whenever the event fires on itself, but also when the event fires on one of it's descendants.

The reason why it's working with `mousenter` and `mouseleave` is that those events are handled differently by the browser. But be aware that they are not supported by all browsers.